# error when accessing API key from .env file

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I am trying to add a google maps to my page in a React app with a pin dropped on a location.

All works fine when I hardcode the APIKEY in to the component like,

```
bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 
                '<api=key'
              }}
```

but when I put the API Key in a .env file, it doesnt work (I know .env files aren't totally secure as the key can be read in the dev tools on google, but I am not overly worried about that at the moment.)

so far I have this in my Map component,

```
  <GoogleMapReact
   bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 
       `${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}`
   }}
   defaultCenter={location}
   defaultZoom={zoom}
  >
```

I have `console.log(`${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}`)` and it logs as expected. But when I run the app I get an error,

```
util.js:66 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key
```

in my `.env` file I have,

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY=<api=key>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. I didnt need `;` in the .env file as it was adding this to the api key which is why google was saying it was invalid